# ant ReplaceRegExp to replace string with double quotes

Tags: java, .net, regex, ant, build-automation

Using ANT I'm trying to find/replace a string with spaces and double quotes using ANT replaceregexp task.

Actual tag in xml

```
    <ser:debug enabled="false">
```

Below both failed.

```
"<replaceregexp file="filepath" match="debug enabled="false"" replace="debug enabled="true"" byline="true" />"
```

And

```
"<replaceregexp file="filepath" match="debug\ enabled\=\"false\"" replace="debug\ enabled\=\"true\"" byline="true" />"
```

I'm getting this error:

> Element type "replaceregexp" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

However this one works fine without any issue for a different tag...since no such special char.

```
<replaceregexp file="filepath" match="sql-debug-mode>true" replace="sql-debug-mode>false" byline="true" />
```

Comment: Tried this way with xml char entity  (not sure i'm doing the right thing)  `<replaceregexp file="filepath" match="debug enabled=&quotfalse&quot" replace="debug enabled=&quottrue&quot" byline="true" />` but getting this error
The reference to entity "quotfalse" must end with the ';' delimiter.

Comment: You missed the semi-colon on the entity: `&quot;`

Comment: Thanks very much, have also tried surrounding with ' single quote...that worked

Answer (score 0):

have also tried surrounding with ' single quote...that worked – enthuguy

Answer (score 0):

I need to replace dir="EAR" with "${stage.prj.dir}EAR"

This works for me

```
<replaceregexp file="${stage.prj.dir}/LMS_HOME/EAR/ExtLib/jar_replace.xml"
               match="&quot;EAR&quot;"
               replace="&quot;${stage.prj.dir}EAR&quot;"
               byline="true"/>
```